# Rails - active admin html appears instead of hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working in [Active Admin](https://activeadmin.info/) and i am using `link_to` so when i click on a user i get taken to that user profile for some reason instead of hyperlink i am seeing the html.

I have tried two approaches

**First**

```
  row 'Users' do
    User
      .joins(:permissions)
      .where(permissions: {admin: true})
      .map{|x| link_to(x.email, [:admin, x]).html_safe }
      .join(', ')
  end
```

Using this approach i see `<a href="/admin/users/171625">email@example.com</a>` rather than a hyper link

**Second**

```
row 'Users' do
    User
      .joins(:permissions)
      .where(permissions: {admin: true})
      .map{|x| div (link_to(x.email, [:admin, x])).html_safe}
      .join(', ')

  end
```

Using this approach what I see in browser is as following
A hyperlink and a raw html of a hyperlink 
[image]

**Third**

```
  row 'Users' do
    User
      .joins(:permissions)
      .where(permissions: {admin: true})
      .map do |user|
        raw(link_to user.email, admin_user_path(user))
      end
      .join(', ')
  end
```

Result: displays as an html as well

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. All i want is to link the user to their profile page.

Comment: Your first example *is* a link.

Comment: use "raw" after do statement

Comment: @JackBracken yes the first is a link but it does not render as a link, it renders as html

Comment: @SachinR does not work either, please see the updated question i have posted that example too

Answer (score 1):

When you use html_safe or raw (raw helper will call html_safe inside it), you'll get an instance of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, which will not be escaped when rendered.
But if you take an array of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`s (like in your examples) and apply `join` to it, you'll get a `String` instance, which will be escaped.

So you'll have to apply `raw` or `html_safe` to the resulting string:

```
  row 'Users' do
    raw(User
      .joins(:permissions)
      .where(permissions: { admin: true })
      .map do |user|
        link_to user.email, admin_user_path(user)
      end
      .join(', '))
  end

  row 'Users' do
    (User
      .joins(:permissions)
      .where(permissions: { admin: true })
      .map do |user|
        link_to user.email, admin_user_path(user)
      end
      .join(', ')).html_safe
  end
```

or use `safe_join` to join `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`s:

```
  row 'Users' do
    safe_join(User
             .joins(:permissions)
             .where(permissions: { admin: true })
             .map do |user|
               link_to(user.email, admin_user_path(user)).html_safe
              end, ', ')
  end
```

Comment: could you care to explain how is this going to fix the problem and how is this different than any of the solution mentioned in the question? I dont want to copy and paste, I want to understand what is it that I am doing wrong.